# Swing GUI for appointment system

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

could anybody advise me on how to connect my GUI to my base classes
I have wrote the gui and designed it, but now need the GUI to interact with another class I made.

edit: added updated code to my thread, added new methods to print out text to the TextFields when buttons are pressed. I.e.  Show Appointments, displays all of the appointments in the textfield next to the button. 
Also, need to try and add an option for a user to enter their own appointment using the Gregorian calendar format

```
   package com.appointmentsys;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


/**
 * 
 * @author Daniel Burke 
 *
 */
public class ControllerGUI extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

     static JButton button1;
     static JButton button2;
     static JButton button3;
     static JButton button4;
     static JTextField ta;
     static JTextField ta1;
     static JTextField ta2;
     static JTextField ta3;


    AppointmentBook appBook = new AppointmentBook();

    public void MainForm(){

        button1.addActionListener(this);
        button2.addActionListener(this);
        button3.addActionListener(this);
        button4.addActionListener(this);
        ta.addActionListener(this);
        ta1.addActionListener(this);
        ta2.addActionListener(this);
        ta3.addActionListener(this);

                        }

  public static void CreateandShowGUI(){

      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,10));

      button1 = new JButton("Add appointment");
      ta = new JTextField();
      /*
      TextAreaOutputStream taos = new TextAreaOutputStream( ta, 60 );
      PrintStream ps = new PrintStream( taos );
      System.setOut( ps );
      System.setErr( ps );
*/
      button2 = new JButton("Remove appointment");
      ta1 = new JTextField();
      button3 = new JButton("Show appointment");
      ta2 = new JTextField();
      button4 = new JButton("Search appointments");
      ta3 = new JTextField();

      frame.setContentPane(panel);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);


     panel.add(new JLabel("         "));
     panel.add(new JLabel("        Please select an option: "));
     panel.add(new JLabel("         "));
     panel.add(new JLabel("         "));
     panel.add(button1);
     panel.add(ta);
        panel.add(button2);
        panel.add(ta1); 
        panel.add(button3);
        panel.add(ta2);
        panel.add(button4);
        panel.add(ta3);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Appointment System"));

}
  public  class EventHandler implements ActionListener{


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if(e.getSource() == button1){
            appBook.add(new Appointment(new GregorianCalendar(2015, 8+1, 1, 11, 30 ), new GregorianCalendar(2015, 10, 14, 11, 30), "Dyland"));
            }
            else if(e.getSource() == button3){
                String appointmentInfo = appBook.getAppointment(0).toString();
                ta2.setText(appointmentInfo);



            }

        }
  }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        CreateandShowGUI();
        }
            });
        }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }




  }

package com.appointmentsys;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

/**
 * 
 * Controller class will test Appointment/AppointmentBook
 * @author  Daniel Burke 
 *
 */
public class Controller {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Appointment a1 = new Appointment(new GregorianCalendar(2015, 8+1, 14, 10, 30 ), new GregorianCalendar(2015, 10, 14, 11, 30), "Danny");
        Appointment a2 = new Appointment(new GregorianCalendar(2015, 8+1, 20, 9, 00), new GregorianCalendar(2015, 10, 20, 10, 10), "JOhn");
        Appointment a3 = new Appointment(new GregorianCalendar(2015, 8+1, 21, 14, 00), new GregorianCalendar(2015, 10, 21, 16, 00), "Steve");               
        Appointment a4 = new Appointment(new GregorianCalendar(2015, 8+1, 21, 14, 00), new GregorianCalendar(2015, 10, 21, 16, 00), "Patrick");

        AppointmentBook appBook = new AppointmentBook();
        appBook.add(a1);
        appBook.add(a2);
        appBook.add(a3);
        appBook.add(a4);

        System.out.println("Appointment is in book: " + appBook.isInBook(a1));
        System.out.println("Appointment is in book: " + appBook.isInBook(a4));
        //appBook.remove(a1);
        appBook.ShowAppointments();


    }
}

    package com.appointmentsys;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;


public class Appointment {

    //Appointments have start/end times & dates.
    //Every appointment has a title.

    private GregorianCalendar startDateTime;
    private GregorianCalendar endDateTime;
    private String eventTitle;

    //default constructor
    public Appointment(){
        this.startDateTime = null;
        this.endDateTime = null;
        this.eventTitle = "";
    }

    //constructor

    public Appointment(GregorianCalendar startDate, GregorianCalendar endDate, String eventTitle){
        this.startDateTime = startDate;
        this.endDateTime = endDate;
        this.eventTitle = eventTitle;
    }


    public GregorianCalendar getStartDateTime() {
        return startDateTime;
    }
    public void setStartDateTime(GregorianCalendar startDateTime) {
        this.startDateTime = startDateTime;
    }
    public GregorianCalendar getEndDateTime() {
        return endDateTime;
    }
    public void setEndDateTime(GregorianCalendar endDateTime) {
        this.endDateTime = endDateTime;
    }
    public String getEventTitle() {
        return eventTitle;
    }
    public void setEventTitle(String eventTitle) {
        this.eventTitle = eventTitle;
    }

    //toString() method to represent an appointment object
    public String toString(){

        String strdate = null; 
        int hours = 0;
        String hrs = null;
        int mins = 0;
        String min = null;

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/YYYY");

        if (getStartDateTime() != null ){
            strdate = sdf.format(getStartDateTime().getTime());
            hours = getStartDateTime().get(Calendar.HOUR);
            hrs = Integer.toString(hours);
            mins = getStartDateTime().get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            min = Integer.toString(mins);
        }
        String s = getEventTitle()+" "+ strdate+" "+ hrs +": "+min;
        return "Appointment: \n" + s;



    }


}

    package com.appointmentsys;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AppointmentBook {

    private static final int NOTFOUND = -1; //NOTFOUND int constant 

    //We can use an ArrayList to store appointments (you could use a database)

    private ArrayList<Appointment> appointmentList  = new ArrayList<Appointment>();

    //add method to appointmentbook

    /**
     * Adds appointments to the appointmentList 
     * @param a
     */

    public void add(Appointment a ){

    appointmentList.add(a);
    }
    /**
     * create a new arrayList for all appoints then return all
     * @return
     */

    public ArrayList<Appointment> getAllAppointments(){

        ArrayList<Appointment> all = new ArrayList<Appointment>(appointmentList);
        return all;
    }
    /**
     * Prints out the list of all the appointsment made
     * 
     */
    public void ShowAppointments()
    {
        ArrayList<Appointment> all = new ArrayList<Appointment>(appointmentList);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("All appointments: \n");


        for(Appointment a: all)
        {
            System.out.println(a);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    /**
     * returns -1 if no appointment is found
     * @param tofind
     * @return
     */
    private int find(Appointment tofind)
    {
        int i = 0;

        for(Appointment a: appointmentList)
        {
            if(a.equals(tofind)) return i;
            i++;
        }
                return NOTFOUND;
    }
    /**
     * removes an appointment from the appointmentList
     * @param toRemove
     */
    public void remove(Appointment toRemove){

        int location = find(toRemove);
        if(location != NOTFOUND) appointmentList.remove(location);
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Appointment not found");
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param a
     * @return
     */
    public boolean isInBook(Appointment a){
        return find(a) != NOTFOUND;

    }

    public String getAppointment(int i) {

        return appointmentList.get(i).toString();

    }

}
```

Comment: If you don't know how to "connect" two classes, you should be learning the basics, not writing UI code.

Answer (score 1):

You have most of the code already. You have a instance of your AppointmentBook class in your ControllerGUI

```
AppointmentBook appBook = new AppointmentBook();
```

You can use that appBook object in your event handler.

```
public  class EventHandler implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource() == button1) {
            appBook.add(new Appointment());
        }
    }
}
```

I don't see the code for the Appointment class there, but you can call whatever the constructor is for your Appointment class in the appBook.add call.

E.g.

```
appBook.add(new Appointment("21-01-2016", "Meeting"));
```

If you had a constructor that takes in 2 strings for an appointment

Edit:

After seeing your additional code I see you have 2 main() methods. So these are truly 2 separate programs.

You can try to combine the 2 main methods.

Instead of making a bunch of appointments in the main method. You should test out adding appointments by clicking one of the buttons.

public  class EventHandler implements ActionListener{

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource() == button1) {
            appBook.add(new Appointment(new GregorianCalendar(2015, 8+1, 14, 10, 30 ), new GregorianCalendar(2015, 10, 14, 11, 30), "Danny"));
        }
    }
}
```

You can also make another button check to call your appBook.ShowAppointments() method.

Adding a harcoded appointment like that isn't ideal though. So test it out a bit and then add some methods that allow you to pass in the values.

You won't need the other main method at all to get this to work, just the one with the CreateandShowGUI call.

Edit2:
You have a toString method in your Appointment class already.
Add a getAppointment method to your AppointmentBook class that allows you to get any appointment by an index, taking that index as a parameter. Something that would return `appointmentList.get(index);`

So in your eventHandler you can use that to set your text field.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource() == button3) {
            String appointmentInfo = appBook.getAppointment(0).toString();
            ta.setText(appointmentInfo);
        }
    }
```

This assumes that you have at least one appointment in your appBook object. So you'll have to add some code to check that the appBook isn't empty before trying to set the text.

Edit3:

You aren't actually using your EventHandler. This is what your ControllerGUI file should look like:

```
public class ControllerGUI extends JPanel {

    static JButton button1;
    static JButton button2;
    static JButton button3;
    static JButton button4;
    static JTextField ta;

    static AppointmentBook appBook = new AppointmentBook();
    static EventHandler eventHandler;

    public static void CreateandShowGUI() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));

        button1 = new JButton("Add appointment");
        button2 = new JButton("Remove appointment");
        button3 = new JButton("Show appointment");
        ta = new JTextField();
        button4 = new JButton("Search appointments");

        eventHandler = new EventHandler();
        button1.addActionListener(eventHandler);
        button2.addActionListener(eventHandler);
        button3.addActionListener(eventHandler);
        button4.addActionListener(eventHandler);

        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        panel.add(new JLabel("         "));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Please select an option: "));
        panel.add(new JLabel("         "));
        panel.add(button1);
        panel.add(button2);
        panel.add(button3);
        panel.add(button4);
        panel.add(ta);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Appointment System"));

    }

    public static class EventHandler implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == button1) {
                appBook.add(new Appointment(new GregorianCalendar(2015, 8 + 1, 14, 10, 30), new GregorianCalendar(2015, 10, 14, 11, 30),
                        "Danny"));
            }

            if (e.getSource() == button3) {
                ta.setText(appBook.getAppointment(0).toString());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                CreateandShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And the method in your AppointmentBook class should look like this:

```
public Appointment getAppointment(int index) {
    return appointmentList.get(0);
}
```

I would really recommend that you revise a lot of the basics before continuing though. You need to have a better grasp of methods (passing them parameters and returning values). You'll need to get all of that before trying a GUI program of this level.

In the above class I made the EventHandler class static, then I made an instance of it in the CreateandShowGUI class. Then I added the buttons to the EventHandler (actionlistener). This was just done rejigging your code. It would be better to have a class that handled all of this in a separate file, that wasn't a static class. So you could instantiate it and make any and all calls to methods you want without them being static.

That's all the help I can give for now.

Comment: Thanks, I have just added the Appointment class to the thread, forgot to add it originally

Comment: Thank you! Also I added the ShowAppointments() method to my eventhandler, do you know how to print the results to a JTextField?

Comment: You can add a method to your AppointmentBook class to return a String for an appointment, or all appointments. See next edit above.

Comment: public String getAppointment(int i) {
  
  appointmentList.get(i);
  return null;
 }    this is what i added to the Appointment Book and also added else if(e.getSource() == button3){
    String appointmentInfo = appBook.getAppointment(0).toString();
             ta2.setText(appointmentInfo);  to my controller GUI class. Unfortunately, I still do not have anything printing to the TextField. Do you have any suggestions? I'm probably doing something wrong

Comment: Your method is wrong. Your getAppointment method is nearly there, but you need to return the String value. You are just getting the string, but then returning null. You want return appointmentList.get(i);

Comment: 'code' public String getAppointment(int i) {
  
  return appointmentList.get(0).toString();
  
 }
  like this..?

Comment: Looks good to me, except replace the 0 with your parameter i.  public String getAppointment(int i) { return appointmentList.get(i).toString(); }

Answer (score 0):

You should use the MVC method of development,

Your Business Logic is at the bottom accessed from Services that the Gui can call, then you can put a website/swing/any other view system on the top 
more or less accessing an API into your business logic

AppointmentService.addAppointment(Appointment appointment);
AppointmentService.getAppointments();

etc

Answer (score 0):

Start with a simple command line interface (CLI) class.

Just code a class with a `main()` method that exercises AppointmentBook.
Once you understand how AppointmentBook works, return to your GUI.